# MultiIndex look up all indices that have a given value for a given level

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index

I am using a `pandas.Series` with a `MultiIndex` for a bidirectional weighted lookup. I thought it should be easy to also find the corresponding other levels for a given level using the MultiIndex, but I cannot find a simple function `other` that does something like the following:

```
>>> index=pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
...                  [(0, 0),(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(5,7),(8,0),(9,0)],
...                  names=["concept", "word"])
>>> other(index, "word", 0)
{0, 8, 9}
>>> other(index, "concept", 3)
{4}
>>> other(index, "word", 6)
{5}
```

I'm happy to specify level numbers instead of level names and to get any iterable out, not necessarily a set. I only have a 2-level multi-index, so I don't care about how to generalize to a higher-level multi-indices, or even whether it does generalize.

I would be slightly unhappy if this involves iterating over all entries in the MultiIndex and comparing them, because I thought indices are somewhat like multi-key hash tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

You could build up a custom function using a vectorized approach as shown:

```
def other(index, slicing, value):
    arr = np.column_stack(index.values.tolist())
    return (np.delete(arr, slicing, axis=0)[0][arr[slicing]==value])
```

*Usage:*

```
other(index, slicing=index.names.index('word'), value=0)
# array([0, 8, 9])
```

*Timings:*

```
%timeit other(index, slicing=index.names.index('word'), value=0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 43.9 µs per loop
```

---

**Approach 2:**

If you want to use an inbuilt method which gives you the result by mere plugging in values to the respective args, you could opt for [`get_loc_level`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.get_loc_level.html#pandas.MultiIndex.get_loc_level) which gives you the integer location slice corresponding to a label, like so:

*Demo:*

```
index.get_loc_level(key=3, level='concept')[1].ravel()
# array([4], dtype=int64)

index.get_loc_level(key=0, level='word')[1].ravel()
# array([0, 8, 9], dtype=int64)

index.get_loc_level(key=6, level='word')[1].ravel()
# array([5], dtype=int64)
```

*Timings:*

```
%timeit index.get_loc_level(key=0, level='word')[1].ravel()
10000 loops, best of 3: 129 µs per loop
```

So, you get a 3x boost using a custom function rather than implementing using 
the built-in methods for the 2-level multi-index `DF` given.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
>>> index.get_level_values('concept').values[index.get_level_values('word').values == 0]
array([0, 8, 9])

>>> index.get_level_values('concept').values[index.get_level_values('word').values == 6]
array([5])

>>> index.get_level_values('word').values[index.get_level_values('concept').values == 3]
array([4])
```

---

Note that you can easily transform a numpy array to a set:

```
>>> set(np.array([1, 2, 3]))
{1, 2, 3}
```

and wrapping all of the above into some function `other` shouldn't be very difficult.

Comment: That would mean iterating over all entries (even though it's in a numpy `==` operation), which I was hoping some Index magic would allow me to avoid, but at least it's concise, readable and the iteration *is* in numpy.